# 18.04 -- how do I keep the lock screen background when logging in?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, desktop-background

I have a really pretty wallpaper for my lock screen. However when I press enter to log in, it's replaced by an unsightly solid purple background. How do I keep the wallpaper image there while logging in (like how it works on Windows 10)?

This is with the standard GNOME desktop environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the image you want to use into the **`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`**
folder. For example: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/my_image_name.png`

Then:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

OR in some cases:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
```

Search for the following section:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2e3436 url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Change

```
background: #2e3436 url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);
```

to

```
background: #2e3436 url(my_image_name.png);
```

(without path in case you copy your image to **`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`** like `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/my_image_name.png`).

Alternatively, you can also simply set just a color (without wallpaper or texture) with:

```
background: #2e3436;
```

Set `background-repeat` to `repeat` or `no-repeat`. In case your image is a texture, set it to `repeat`. In case wallpaper: `no-repeat`

**Reboot.**

Comment: make sure, the used path to your background image is in an unencrypted part of your hard drive

Comment: for the current image use `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`